# Matplotlib specify axes value inside an interval

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a csv with 200 data points. If I plot it, the x-axis will take default values from 0 to 200. However, 4 data points correspond to each event, so I would like to have values from 0 to 50 on the x-axis.

This is what I have now

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(val, color='blue', label='t1')
ax1.plot(val2, color='red', label='t2')
ax1.plot(val3, color='green', label='t3')
ax1.plot(val5, color='magenta', label='t4')

plt.axis([0,200,0,0.8])

plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Events')
ax1.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Any idea how I can modify this to effectively divide the numbers on the x-axis by 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x=np.arange(0,50,0.25)` as x-value in your plots, as an example:

```
ax1.plot(x,val, color='blue', label='t1')
```

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you are wrong, it is 200. Check `len(np.arange(0,50,0.25))`

Comment: Sorry, it might be the question which might be confusing here, but if you have 200 points from 0 to 50, the step size must be 0.25125...

Comment: In that case you can use `np.linspace(0,50,200)`.

Comment: Yes, that is what the other answer is saying.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're not assigning any x-value to the data points. So it uses their index as default.

Make an array of the required length like `x = np.linspace(0, 50, num=200)` and use it for the plot as `ax1.plot(x, val)`.